# Не понимаю почему не делится окно пополам: на кнопку и панель - должны быть по 50% каждая, так как поставил обоим "constraints.weightx = 0.5"

Tags: java, swing

```java
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    public Window(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Window");
        setBounds(100,300,500,500);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 
        setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weightx = 0.5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.fill = 1;
        add(button,constraints);


        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weightx = 0.5;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.fill = 1;


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        add(panel, constraints);

        revalidate();
    }

}
```

[image: окно поделенное не согласно коду]